# Get Active Directory user object GUID for the current user

Tags: java, windows

For a Java desktop application I would like to get the GUID of the user object in Active Directory that represents the current user.

With the NTSystem class you can only get the SID.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: may be you mean not *GUID* but [*LUID*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379261(v=vs.85).aspx) - the [logon Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378338(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: and current logged on user - can be multiple

Comment: in general need call [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx) with self process token and *TokenStatistics* and use *AuthenticationId* from [TOKEN_STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379632(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: No I mean GUID, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx

Maybe logged on is not the right term then, I want to get the GUID of the user that is return by the NTSystem class and in C# with UserPrincipal.Current.Guid;

Comment: I don't know whether Java contains any classes for interacting with Active Directory.  If nobody can come up with a better answer, you might have to use JNI or similar.